# That aside meaning

Tags: meaning

The following is from the Godfather movie:

> The Don: I forgot the vengeance of my son. But I have selfish reasons.
>   My youngest son was supposed to leave this country because of this
>   Sollozzo bussiness. And I have to make arrangements to bring him back
>   here safely. Cleared of all these false charges. But I'm a
>   superstitious man. If an unlucky accident should befall him, r if he
>   should be shot by a police officer, or if he should hang himself in
>   his jail ceil, or if he struck by a bolt of lightning. Then I'm going
>   to blame of the people in his room and that I do not forgive. ***But,
>   that aside*** let me say that I swear onthe souls of my gradchildreans
>   that I will not be the who break the peace we've made here today.

What does ***that aside*** mean here?

Comment: But putting that aside.  But discounting all the aforementioned

Comment: A few transcription errors; here's an interesting one repaired:   "... I will not be *the one to  break* the peace..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a complicated quote, because the character is not able to speak directly or honestly to the people in the room.  It becomes more clear if we simplify it, and add the implied context:

> My son had to leave the country [because he shot a corrupt policeman
>   who was working for one of you] and I have been busy making sure he
>   could return. [I would never accuse you of plotting to harm my family,
>   but] Under the circumstances, I will blame you if anything at all
>   should happen to him.
>
> But, [putting my promise to enact bloody revenge on you] aside, I will
>   not be the one who breaks the peace.

A more direct conversation might be to say "Sure, we've been at war, but now we're at peace.  If any of you knuckeheads decide to get payback on my boy, I will personally end each and every one of you. Having said that, I'm willing to accept the terms of peace."

The author is using "but, that aside" to say that what came before should be ignored for the moment.  For another example, consider a conversation:

> "Would you like to go see that new movie?  Julia said it was really
>   good."
>
> "Julia stole my lunch last week and I'm still mad about that. 
>   But, that aside, I do want to go see the movie."

It's interesting to note that putting something aside is not the same as forgetting about it.  It is similar to "putting it on the back burner" or "tabling that for now" - it is implied that it will be important later, but not right now.

Answer (score 0):

[Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/aside_1) explains,

> ***aside*** (adverb)
>
> used for telling someone that what you are mentioning is not as important as what you are going to say next

Example:

> *You’re right to mention her home circumstances, but that aside, how is her school work?*